# Coldfusion display only if content exist

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coldfusion-9

If the value exist I would like to display the content otherwise not 
Any idea how to do it? with recordcount isn't working maybe over javascript?
thank you for your tips

```
<div container>
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="panel-default" style="background-color:##FFFFFF">
<div class="form-group"><cfoutput>#getinfo(SERVICES)#</cfoutput>  
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried <cfif> tag? is a simple condition inside the .cfm template

Comment: i tried:
`<cfif #getinfo# contains "ZUP"
CODE ABOVE
<cfelse>
</cfif>`  but is not working

Comment: Welcome to S.O. I think you forgot to explain a few things :-) like ... 1) what type of object is `getinfo` (query, function, ..)?. 2) what do mean by "if the value exists". Did you mean the query returned 0 records?  3) Also, showing a dump of `getinfo` would help us better understand the issue `<cfdump var="#getinfo#">`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to wrap the entire template inside the `cfoutput`

```
<cfoutput>
 <cfif getinfo EQ "ZIP">

  <div class="form-group">
   #getinfo(SERVICES)#  
  </div>

 </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i get the following message: can't compare complex object types as simple value.

any idea?

Comment: you have to check the type of data is the object outputting. Do <cfdump
var = "#getinfo#"> to dump the object value to the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ListFind](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listfind.html).
You don’t need to put `#` inside of `cfif`. Also you don't need to wrap using `cfoutput`. It's a matter of taste, I think. (Of course, when you want to show a variable, it’s necessary.)